# How can I access an instance of a class from a child instance?

Tags: javascript

I have a class named "Main", with one instance named "main". The "main" instance has two properties that are instances of other classes, named "player" and "background". I want the child instances to be able to use each other, as well as the "main" instance. Below is my attempt, which throws an error: "main is undefined".

```
class Player {
    constructor() {
    }

    x = 10;
    y = 20;
};

class Background {
    constructor() {
    }

    backgroundCenterX = main.player.x;
    backgroundCenterY = main.player.y;
    // the previous two lines throw an error
};

class Main {
    constructor() {
        this.background = new Background();
        this.player = new Player();
    }
};

var main = new Main();
```

I have tried a few things, including passing the "main" instance by reference to the constructors of the child instances, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I think the code is throwing an error because the "Main" constructor hasn't finished running when the "main" instance is referenced.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I doubt this would work in the first place, as changes to player x+y won't be reflected to background's coords.

Comment: @RyanWilson I edited the question to fix this - sorry

Comment: @SuperStormer in my actual code, I have that in a function which is bound to the two.js update function. I should have thought of that before posting.

Comment: @MisterJojo I'll do that in future

Comment: This is a poor design. Class dependencies typically should not be circular. If you really want to do it anyways, your instance of `main` should pass itself into its dependencies, rather than using a single global variable everywhere.

Comment: @user229044 Should I place variables that multiple classes need to access higher up in the dependency tree?

Comment: @potato-burger no, typically you would pass them in as dependencies.

Comment: @user229044 sorry for the dumb question, but how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the main into the child constructors. But the order matters, you have to construct and assign the player first if the background constructor is to access it on main.

```js
class Player {
    constructor(main) {
      this.main = main;
    }
    

    x = 10;
    y = 20;
};

class Background {
    constructor(main) {
      this.main = main;
      this.backgroundCenterX = this.main.player.x;
      this.backgroundCenterY = this.main.player.y;
    }
};

class Main {
    constructor() {
        this.player = new Player(this);
        this.background = new Background(this);
    }
};

var main = new Main();

console.log(main);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible for the player and background classes to access each other?

Comment: Not from within the constructors, that can only be done one way, in the order they are constructed and assigned to main. After that however, they absolutely can reach through main to each other (in methods and property getters). As others have noted though, this isn't really a good design. This leads to very tightly coupled classes, making them very fragile to later changes.

Comment: I'll try not to rely on circular dependencies too much, but thanks for the info. I can't upvote this yet becuase I don't have enough reputation, but I've marked it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `main` instance to the `Constructor` of `Player` and `Background`.

Then you can access it via `this.main`

```js
class Player {
    constructor(main) {
      this.main = main;
    }

    x = 10;
    y = 20;
};

class Background {
    constructor(main) {
      this.main = main;
    }

    doSomeThing() {
      const backgroundCenterX = this.main.player.x;
      const backgroundCenterY = this.main.player.y;
      console.log(backgroundCenterX, backgroundCenterY);
    }
    
};

class Main {
    constructor() {
        this.background = new Background(this);
        this.player = new Player(this);
    }

    doSomeThing() {
      this.background.doSomeThing();
    }
};

var main = new Main();
main.doSomeThing()
```